# CakePHP counterCache associated table field won't update on delete()

Tags: cakephp

I have the following tables:  `causes`, `users`, `transactions`

`Cause hasMany Transaction` and `User hasMany Transaction`

`Transaction belongsTo Cause` and `Transaction belongsTo User`

Both my `causes` and `users` tables have `transaction_count` fields and my `belongsTo` has `counterCache => true` on both associations.

Both of my `hasMany` clauses have `dependent => true` and my `foreignKeys` are set up correctly in that if I delete a Cause, all of it's associated Transactions are deleted as well.

It is also working, in that when I create a `Transaction`, the `transaction_count` field in both my `users` and `causes` tables updates correctly.  Here is the breakdown:

1.) Create a `cause`

2.) Create a `transaction`

RESULT:  `causes[ 15 ][ 'transaction_count' ]` increases by 1 correctly

RESULT:  `users[ 1 ][ 'transaction_count' ]` increases by 1 correctly

3.) Manually delete a `transaction` ( `$transaction->delete( $id )` )

RESULT:  `causes[ 15 ][ 'transaction_count' ]` decreases by 1 correctly

RESULT:  `users[ 1 ][ 'transaction_count' ]` decreases by 1 correctly

4.) FAILURE:

If I create the `Cause` and `Transaction` and then delete the `Cause` using `$this->Cause->delete( $id )`, even though all of the `transactions` are deleted in the database (along with the `Cause`), the `transaction_count` in my `users` table is not updated to reflect the decrease.

I imagine this is because `$this->Transaction->delete()` is not getting called explicitly, but it is instead getting deleted due to its association with `Cause`?

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `causes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cause_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**User.php**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Transaction' => array(
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

**Cause.php**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Cause extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Transaction' => array(
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

**Transaction.php**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Transaction extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'counterCache' => true
        ),
        'Cause' => array(
            'counterCache' => true
        )
    );
}
```

**Controller**

```
$this->Cause->query('TRUNCATE TABLE users');
$user['User'] = array(
    'name' => 'aaa'
);
$this->Cause->Transaction->User->create($user);
$this->Cause->Transaction->User->save(null, false);
$userId = $this->Cause->Transaction->User->getLastInsertID();
$this->Cause->query('TRUNCATE TABLE causes');
$cause['Cause'] = array(
    'name' => 'aaa'
);
$this->Cause->create($cause);
$this->Cause->save(null, false);
$causeId = $this->Cause->getLastInsertID();
$this->Cause->query('TRUNCATE TABLE transactions');
$transaction['Transaction'] = array(
    'name' => 'aaa',
    'user_id' => $userId,
    'cause_id' => $causeId
);
$this->Cause->Transaction->create($transaction);
$this->Cause->Transaction->save(null, false);
$this->Cause->Transaction->create($transaction);
$this->Cause->Transaction->save(null, false);
$transaction['Transaction'] = array(
    'name' => 'aaa',
    'user_id' => $userId,
    'cause_id' => 99
);
$this->Cause->Transaction->create($transaction);
$this->Cause->Transaction->save(null, false);
$this->Cause->delete($causeId);
$cause = $this->Cause->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Cause.id' => $causeId
    )
));
$transactions = $this->Cause->Transaction->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Transaction.cause_id' => $causeId
    )
));
$user = $this->Cause->Transaction->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $userId
    )
));
pr($cause);
pr($transactions);
pr($user);

if (is_a($this->Cause, 'Cause')) {
    echo 'Cause';
}
if (is_a($this->Cause->Transaction, 'Transaction')) {
    echo 'Transaction';
}
if (is_a($this->Cause->Transaction->User, 'User')) {
    echo 'User';
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => aaa
            [transaction_count] => 1
        )

)
CauseTransactionUser
```

It works ok.
Double check for typos in models and check if cake is using your models and not the ones that are created on the fly if some model is missing.

Comment: Thank you Kamil, your solution was VERY helpful and lead me in the right direction.  I started changing names of my model references to see where the discrepancy was, and found that I had `Cause->hasMany = array( '**Transactions**' => array ( 'className' => 'Transaction', ... ) );`.  Changing `Transactions` to `Transaction` seems to have fixed the problem.  I thought this was just an alias though; why would it have an effect on cascading deletion?  Or is my understanding of this syntax off?

Comment: Your syntax is ok. Should be working ok if You change 'counterCache' => true to 'counterCache' => 'transaction_count'